# How to correctly save associated entities?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

Let's say we have the following three domain model entities: `Company`, `Departament`, and `Employee`.

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstrutor
public class Employee {
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Department department;

    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", nullable = false)
    private int department_id;
}

@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstrutor
public class Department {
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Company company;

    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    private int company_id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Employee> employees;
}

@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstrutor
private class Company {
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<Department> departments;
}
```

For each entity, we have `Repositories` which extend `JpaRepository`, `Services`, and `Controllers`. In each `Service` we `@Autowire` the respective `Repository`, and in each entity `Controller` we call methods from the entity `Service`.

**My issue is the following**: I cannot save an entire `Company`, because the `Departments` require a `Company` ID, and `Employees` a `Deparment` ID. So, firstly, in my `CompanyService` I save and then clear the `departments` list, do a `saveAndFlush` which assigns an ID to my `company`. I assign the received ID to every `company_id` in each entity of the previously saved `departments` list, then attach the list back to the `company` and do another `saveAndFlush`, and I do this one more time for the `employee` list.

```
@RestController
public class CompanyController {
    @Autowire
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @PostMapping("/companies")
    public Company createCompany(@RequestBody Company newCompany) {
        return companyService.createCompany(newCompany);
    }
}

@Service
public class CompanyService {
    @Autowire
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    public Company createCompany(Company company) {
        List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<>(company.getDepartments());
        company.getDepartments().clear();

        companyRepository.saveAndFlush(company);

        int company_id = company.getId();

        departments.forEach (department ->
            department.setCompany_id(company_id);
        );

        //here I save a copy of the previously saved departments, because I still need the employees
        company.getDepartments().addAll(departments.stream().map(department -> department.clone(department)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        company.getDepartments().forEach(department -> department.getEmployees().clear());

        companyRepository.saveAndFlush(company);

        //here I assign each employee it's corresponding department ID
        for (int i = 0; i < company.getDepartments().size(); i++) {
            Department departmentInSavedCompany = company.getDepartments().get(i);
            Department departmentWhichStillHasEmployees = departments.get(i);

            departmentWhichStillHasEmployees.setId(departmentInSavedCompany.getId());
            departmentWhichStillHasEmployees.getEmployees().forEach(employee -> employee.setDepartment_id(departmentInSavedCompany.getId()));
        }

        company.getDepartments.clear();
        company.getDepartments.addAll(departments);

        return companyRepository.saveAndFlush(company);
    }
}

@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Integer> {

}
```

I currenty do not like this implementation neither do I find it good. Which is the correct approach for this situation?

Comment: why do you have the referenced ids as separate properties in your entities?

Comment: because when POSTing a new employee, I can just pass the department id to establish the relation. `POST { "name" : "New Employee", "department_id" : 1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with JPA, do not work with IDs, work with object references.

In your case, this means removing the id attributes that duplicate the references.

In order to obtain the proper entities for IDs use [`JpaRepository.getOne`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-). It will return either the entity if it is already in the 1st level cache or a proxy just wrapping the id, so it won't hit the database.

This allows you to assemble your object graph and persist it in one pass starting with the entity having no references to other entities.

You might also consider configuring cascading, if you consider entities to be part of the same Aggregate, i.e. they should be loaded and persisted together.

Comment: I have implemented cascading. So without using IDs, let's say we send a `POST` for creating a **department** with the following `RequestBody` : `{"name": "depart_name", "employees" : ["name" : "employee_name"]`, just mapping this body to the **department** model and saving it using `DepartmentRepository.saveAndFlush(newDepart)` will be sufficient?

Comment: Also, how should my request body look for updating a department and it's employees, example `{"name": "UpdatedDepart_name", "employees" : ["name" : "UpdatedEmployee_name"]`, we can get the **id** for the department from the `Path Variable` but how can we get the ids for the employees we want to update?

Comment: To the first question: yes.
To the second: Sorry, to little experience with the REST side to give a confident answer, but I'd guess: pass a url if it has it's own repository. Sorry again, no idea how to exactly do that.

Comment: But let's say I want to add a new employee, how can I reference it's department if i remove the id field from it's model?. Something like this? `POST` `{"name" : "createdEmp", "department": {"id":1}}`

Comment: Again, that should probably be an URL to the department with id 1. But I'm not knowledgeable enough to give exact details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was solved by removing the ID property from the models and redesigning from there. So if anyone runs into this they should reconsider their model properties.